# Extension not clicking properly, console w/ same commands working fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-services

My extension doesn't seem to be clicking things correctly when moving one thread to another place, however when I use the same code inside the console on the same page, it works perfectly fine. I have seen in other posts that say you have to have document.ready before it, and that you should be having a timeout(function() {}), and I tried doing that however it still doesn't work.

Here is the code for what I'm trying to do:

```
if(wasAccepted() == true) {
        $("document").ready(function() {
            $(document.getElementsByClassName('menuTrigger menuTrigger--prefix')).click()
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(document.getElementsByClassName('menuPrefix label label--lightGreen')[0]).trigger('click').delay(20);
            },30);
        });
```

and here is a short gif of what it does do:
https://i.imgur.com/LopYGUl.gifv

here is me inserting the same code into the console, and it doing what's expected:
https://i.imgur.com/2HXyCPw.gifv

Comment: Why use `$(document.getElementsByClassName('menuTrigger menuTrigger--prefix'))`? Just use jquery.

Comment: $("document").ready(function() { is for the initial page load. If you are loading a new page, than what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: So can I do window.load? or is there a better way of doing this? Because the button to save the movement changes works, but this one is the only one that doesn't.